# How to define model to unmarshall post data without root element name

Tags: spring, rest, jaxb, cxf, jax-rs

I have a REST API which gets following in post request body to create that data in back end:

```
{
  "key": "mykey30",
  "value": "my long value"
}
```

and this is how I defined my model:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Entity {

  private String key;
  private String value;
}
```

and this is how I defined my service end point:

```
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("/buckets/{bucket_id}/entities/{key}")
public CacheResponse createEntity(Entity entity, @PathParam("bucket_id") String bucket_id, @PathParam("key") String key);
```

I am now getting this exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"key"). Expected elements are <{}cacheEntity>
```

which makes sense and it goes away when I post this json:

```
{
  "Entity": {
    "key": "mykey30",
    "value": "My New Value"
  }
}
```

but my clients will post requests like the one which I have pasted earlier, without "Entity" wrapper.

How do I annotate & define my model to ignore root element?

I am using cxf 3.0.3, Spring 3.2.13.RELEASE & Jettison 1.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to configure the [`JSONProvider`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/provider/json/JSONProvider.html).

- The property for marshalling (to unwrap) is [`setDropRootElement(boolean)`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/provider/json/JSONProvider.html#setDropRootElement%28boolean%29)
- The property for unmarshalling (allowing unwrapped) is [`setSupportUnwrapped(boolean)`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/provider/json/JSONProvider.html#setSupportUnwrapped%28boolean%29)

With xml config, you might have something like

```
<jaxrs:server [...] >
    [...]
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
            <property name="dropRootElement" value="true"/>
            <property name="supportUnwrapped" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Maven dependency (which I assume you already have)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer by @peeskillet works nicely.

One another way out is to use Jackson as JSON provider, it supports this functionality out of the box. All you have to do is to add this to your beans config xml:

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
```

and this as dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Personally I would go with this way. I didn't know if it was an option or not for you. I prefer Jackson over any other JSON processing framework